# Failure of a simple nested loop

Tags: python, loops

I am implementing a nested for loop which the inner for loop is about looping through combinations. However, I dont understand why this do not work...

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
comb = combinations(range(0, 3), 2)
for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in comb:
        print(i, j)
```

The output is:

```
0 (0, 1)
0 (0, 2)
0 (1, 2)
```

It did not loop the outer loop...however if it is not combination, it works as expected

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in range(0, 2):
        print(i, j)
```

the results are:

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

Am i missing some important properties of combinations? I could not figure out why this do not work...sorry if it is a stupid question, any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you've exhausted the `combinations` iterator on the first loop

Comment: @AndrewAllen thank you for the help, does that mean I should create the combinations every single loop?

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem.

Comment: Could you add the expected `input` and `output` to the question please

Comment: My aim was to reuse the `combination` in every loop, andrew has answered my question! thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to a list first

```
from itertools import combinations
comb = list(combinations(range(0, 3), 2))
for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in comb:
        print(i, j)
```

Result

```
0 (0, 1)
0 (0, 2)
0 (1, 2)
1 (0, 1)
1 (0, 2)
1 (1, 2)
```

Comment: thank you very much! i didnt know the iterator can be exhausted previously

Comment: no problem, you could also do `for j in combinations(range(0, 3), 2):` and skip the `comb` definition

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is not `combination`, but `product`. The below code should work.

```
from itertools import product
prod = product(range(0, 2), repeat = 2)
for i, j in prod:
    print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, it was actually helpful too. But in my application, combination fits my need better :D